# Find all punctuators in file

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to find all special symbols in file, that has C code(like ::, (), ->, etc.) and add it to list. The problem is that my code only finds 1 symbol(like (, :, -) and so on. How should i rewrite it?

For example: i have this code:

```
struct list_head audit_filter_list[AUDIT_NR_FILTERS] = {
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[0]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[1]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[2]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[3]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[4]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[5]),
#if AUDIT_NR_FILTERS != 6
#error Fix audit_filter_list initialiser
#endif
};
static struct list_head audit_rules_list[AUDIT_NR_FILTERS] = {
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_rules_list[0]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_rules_list[1]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_rules_list[2]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_rules_list[3]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_rules_list[4]),
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_rules_list[5]),
};

DEFINE_MUTEX(audit_filter_mutex);

static void audit_free_lsm_field(struct audit_field *f)
{
    switch (f->type) {
    case AUDIT_SUBJ_USER:
    case AUDIT_SUBJ_ROLE:
    case AUDIT_SUBJ_TYPE:
    case AUDIT_SUBJ_SEN:
    case AUDIT_SUBJ_CLR:
    case AUDIT_OBJ_USER:
    case AUDIT_OBJ_ROLE:
    case AUDIT_OBJ_TYPE:
    case AUDIT_OBJ_LEV_LOW:
    case AUDIT_OBJ_LEV_HIGH:
        kfree(f->lsm_str);
        security_audit_rule_free(f->lsm_rule);
    }
}

static inline void audit_free_rule(struct audit_entry *e)
{
    int i;
    struct audit_krule *erule = &e->rule;

    /* some rules don't have associated watches */
    if (erule->watch)
        audit_put_watch(erule->watch);
    if (erule->fields)
        for (i = 0; i < erule->field_count; i++)
            audit_free_lsm_field(&erule->fields[i]);
    kfree(erule->fields);
    kfree(erule->filterkey);
    kfree(e);
}

void audit_free_rule_rcu(struct rcu_head *head)
{
    struct audit_entry *e = container_of(head, struct audit_entry, rcu);
    audit_free_rule(e);
}
```

i need to extract words like this(not only this, but as example)

```
case
if
IST_HEAD_INIT
#include
switch
#define
audit_free_lsm_field
```

but also i need to extract tokens like this:

```
()
[]
::
->
{}
==
+=
```

Here is my code:

```
 private int find(String text, String ignored_chars, int type)//search for words and operators
{
    if (text.isEmpty()) return 0;
    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);//finder

    while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
        String s;

        try{
            s = str.nextToken(ignored_chars);

            //Comparer
            //1 for letters, 0 for other symbols
            if (type==1) comparer(s);//method of finding new words and add to list.
            if (type==0){
                for(int i=0; i < s.length();i++)//search for brackets and other symbols
                {

                        if((s.charAt(i)=='(')||(s.charAt(i)==')')||(s.charAt(i)==';')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='{')||(s.charAt(i)=='}')||(s.charAt(i)==',')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)==':')||(s.charAt(i)=='*')||(s.charAt(i)=='\'')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='\"')||(s.charAt(i)=='<')||(s.charAt(i)=='>')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='[')||(s.charAt(i)==']')||(s.charAt(i)=='+')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='-')||(s.charAt(i)=='{')||(s.charAt(i)=='}')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='^')||(s.charAt(i)=='&')||(s.charAt(i)=='=')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='|')||(s.charAt(i)=='%')||(s.charAt(i)=='#')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='.')||(s.charAt(i)==',')||(s.charAt(i)=='!')
                            ||(s.charAt(i)=='\t')||(s.charAt(i)=='\n'))

                    {

                        String character = s.substring(i, i+1);
                        if (!(character.isEmpty())){
                            comparer(character);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == s.length()-1) {
                            s = s.replace('(',' ');
                            s = s.replace(')',' ');
                            s = s.replace(';',' ');
                            s = s.trim();
                            comparer(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){System.out.println("Error while check group: "+ignored_chars);}
        //System.out.println(word);  //debug
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and method of analyzing text

```
 public int analyze(String text)
{
    String chars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            + "абвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюяАБВГҐДЕЄЖЗИІЇКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЮЯ"
            + "1234567890~_Ⓡ    \n\t";
    String sign = " .,;:!?+=*-~`  {(//<[]>)}\"\'|&\n\t  \\    ";

    String figure_bracket1 = chars + "} .,;:!?+=*-(//<[]>)\"\'|&\n\t  \\  ";
    String figure_bracket2 = chars + "{ .,;:!?+=*-(//<[]>)\"\'|&\n\t  \\  ";

    String bracket1 = chars + ") .,;:!?+=*-{}//<>[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";
    String bracket2 = chars + "( .,;:!?+=*-{}//<>[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";


    String square_bracket1 = chars + "[ ,.;:!?+=*-{}()//<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\  ";
    String square_bracket2 = chars + "] ,.;:!?+=*-{}()//<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\  ";

    String moreThan = chars + "> ,.;:!?+=*-{}()//[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";
    String lessThan = chars + "< ,.;:!?+=*-{}()//[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";

    String doubleQuotes = chars + " ,.;:!?+=*-{}()//[]<>\'|&\n\t  \\  ";
    String quotes = chars + " ,.;:!?+=*-{}()//[]<>\"|&\n\t  \\    ";

    String semicolon = chars + " .,:!?+=*-{}()//[]<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\    ";
    String comma = chars + " .;:!?+=*-{}()[]//<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\    ";
    String dot = chars + " ,;:!?+=*-{}()[]//<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\  ";

    String double_dot = chars + " .,;!?+=*-{}()//<>[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\   ";
    String multiply = chars + " .,;:!?+=-{}()//<>[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";
    String plus = chars + " .,;:!?=*-{}()//<>[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";
    String minus = chars + " .,;:!?+=*{}()//<>[]\"\'|&\n\t  \\    ";
    String equal = chars + " .,;:!?-+*{}()//<>[]\"\'|&\n \t \\    ";
    String sign_OR = chars + " .,;:!?=-+*{}()//<>[]\"\'&\n\t \\  ";

    String exclamationMark = chars + " ,.;:?+=*-{}()[]//<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\  ";
    String questionMark = chars + " ,.;:!+=*-{}()[]//<>\"\'|&\n\t  \\ ";

    String[] destinationChars = {figure_bracket1, figure_bracket2,
            bracket1, bracket2, square_bracket1, square_bracket2, moreThan,
            lessThan, doubleQuotes, quotes, semicolon, comma, dot, double_dot,
            multiply, plus, minus, equal, sign_OR, exclamationMark, questionMark};

    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("empty field found");
    }

    find(text,sign,1);
    for (int i = 0; i < destinationChars.length; i++)
    {
        find(text, destinationChars[i], 0);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's _very_ complex, can you provide an example of input and what you'd want to match and what not?

Comment: <pre>int acct_parm[3] = {4, 2, 30};
    #define RESUME  (acct_parm[0]) 
    #define SUSPEND  (acct_parm[1]) 
    #define ACCT_TIMEOUT (acct_parm[2]) 
<code>
like if i parse this, i need to get all words + (),[], {}, =.
But i have only (, ), {, }, [, ]

Comment: Please add that example to your question and apply some formatting and please be more specific than "i need to get all words" - the example seems to be small enought to list everything you want to get (and everything else is what you don't want) - as it is now (in your comment) we'd still have to guess and could misunderstand your intentions.

Comment: I've changed description. Hope, you'll help me

Comment: Are you saying that your program is getting, for example, `-` and `>` individually rather than the combined `->`?

Comment: Yes! And i don't know how to change it. I thought about iterate list and combine symbols, but now, i don't think it's a good idea

Comment: Usually you'd write a simple tokenizer (lexical scanner) to do that. Regex can often get you most of the way, but there are usually weird cases in which it falls down.

Comment: yea. i used regex, but half of text just miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea of what you want to match and especially of *what you don't want to match*.

However you could try a regex to extract tokens e.g. something like this:

```
([\p{L}\p{N}_#]+|[<>+\-/*&!=.]+|[\[\]{}()])
```

It matches:

- `[\p{L}\p{N}_#]+`: squences of characters, numbers, underscores and hash tags
- `[<>+\-/*&!=.]+` sequences of one or more symbols like `+`, `+=` etc.
- `[\[\]{}()]` a single opening or closing bracket/brace.

Note that this is meant provide a starting point, it might be necessary to expand/tweak the expressions.

**Example:**

Input:

```
struct list_head audit_filter_list[AUDIT_NR_FILTERS] = {
  LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[0]),
  LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[1]),
  LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[2]),
  LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[3]),
  LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[4]),
  LIST_HEAD_INIT(audit_filter_list[5]),
  #if AUDIT_NR_FILTERS != 6
  #error Fix audit_filter_list initialiser
  #endif
};
```

Tokens:

```
"struct", "list_head", "audit_filter_list", "[", "AUDIT_NR_FILTERS", "]",
"=", "{", "LIST_HEAD_INIT", "(", "audit_filter_list", "[", "0", "]", ")",        
"LIST_HEAD_INIT", "(", "audit_filter_list", "[", "1", "]", ")", 
"LIST_HEAD_INIT", "(", "audit_filter_list", "[", "2", "]", ")", 
"LIST_HEAD_INIT", "(", "audit_filter_list", "[", "3", "]", ")", 
"LIST_HEAD_INIT", "(", "audit_filter_list", "[", "4", "]", ")", 
"LIST_HEAD_INIT", "(", "audit_filter_list", "[", "5", "]", ")", "#if", 
"AUDIT_NR_FILTERS", "!=", "6", "#error", "Fix", "audit_filter_list", 
"initialiser", "#endif", "}"
```

Comment: this is actually, what i need, but i need also to combine brackets, but tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `isLetterorDigit()` of the Character class.

You may check if the character is neither a digit, nor a letter by using this method.

eg:

```
if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i))
{
    //do whatever
}
```